# Trouble splitting string into array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, split, char

I want to split a char string into an array temp_dow.

```
//parse incoming string
char input[] = {"1111111,0000000,1010101"};
char temp_dow[3][7];
char *tok1;
int i = 0;
tok1 = strtok(input, ",");
while (tok1 != NULL) {
    char temp[7];
    strcpy(temp, tok1);
    strcpy(temp_dow[i],temp);
    tok1 = strtok(NULL, ",");
    printf ("<<<<<<<< %s\n",temp_dow[i]);
    i++;
}
printf ("******* %s\n",temp_dow[0]);
printf ("******* %s\n",temp_dow[1]);
printf ("******* %s\n",temp_dow[2]);
```

the outputs don't match up. The temp_dow[] outside the while loop is completely wrong. It's showing the value of the pointer instead of the actual value?

Here's the output.

```
  <<<<<<<< 1111111
  <<<<<<<< 0000000
  <<<<<<<< 1010101
  ******* 1010101
  ******* 
  *******
```

Thanks

Comment: `7` --> `8` : +1 for NUL character.

Comment: `strcpy(temp, tok1); strcpy(temp_dow[i],temp);` - **Why??** Also, allocate space for the NUL-terminator.

Comment: Indeed. Why not simply `strcpy(temp_dow[i], tok1);` ? delete the two lines above that.

Comment: Ah, THANKS! The Nul terminator was the issue.

Comment: Use `strsep()` in newer programs. While `strtok()` is portable, it's unable to handle empty fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strtok documentation specifies:

> This end of the token is automatically replaced by a null-character, and the beginning of the token is returned by the function.

Each of your tokens are 7 digits, and you're allocating 7 chars for each token. However, this doesn't account for the null-character terminator. You actually need space for 8 characters.

You should change your temp_dow declaration to:

```
char temp_dow[3][8];
```